# Change the data range of xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers chart from existing X and Y range to new X and Y range keeping the columns same for all the series

Tags: excel, scatter-plot, excel-charts

I have a xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers chart with four series of X and Y data. I would like to change the X and Y data range from existing to new one by keeping the column same for each of the series. I donot want to enter the column name in the code since I have plenty of such plots to change the range of the data. Please help. I tried using the codes available on the internet (also did the modification) but nothing worked. Basically I couldn't find the code which reads the existing columns and just change the end row numbers for both X and Y data. Some codes suggests to update the new range by entering the cell address but its hard to do that for each of the curves with plenty of charts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.